# How to target 32 bit flash player on win 7 64 bit

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have win7 64 bit on my desktop and win7 32 bit on my laptop. I recently upgraded my php to 5.6.2 and amfphp to 2.2.2. As a result I had to modify several ActionScript 3 scripts to access my data. I got the scripts working on my 32 bit laptop, but they looked "fractured" on win 7 64 bit.

I know that the 64 bit flash player installer now installs both a 32 bit version and a 64 bit version of flash player.

Is there a way to specify that these AS3 scripts are to use the 32 bit flash player when launching with 32 bit Firefox on a 64 bit system?

Comment: Problem unclear, describe "fractured". AS3 applications do not target any specific architecture and should run identically in any browser/projector/etc as long as runtime environment (that includes security sandbox issues) satisfy their requirements.

Comment: "Fractured" such as distorted, broken, parts of the animation appearing much larger than the rest. Some scripts don't run at all. This is all on win7 64 bit.

Comment: Compare Flash Player versions installed in both places. The other sources of irregularities could be: 1) different browsers (at the very least IE != FF != Chrome even with the same Player version) or 2) GPU/Stage3D-related issues (some configurations allow 4096x4096 textures and some does not).

Answer (score 1):

An Adobe Staff member provided the following info and upon loading Firefox 54.0b6 (beta) I found that he was right. Most of my animations run as expected, although some of the games run with significant lag time on keyboard nav.

"Just for clarity, the bitness of Flash Player is dependent on the bitness of the host browser.  If you're running a 32-bit browser on a 64-bit OS, you're still going to get the 32-bit Flash Player.  The only case where you'll get 64-bit Flash Player at runtime is when you're running a 64-bit browser on a 64-bit operating system."

"I was able to reproduce this on Win7 x64 with Firefox 54.0b4 (32-bit), but upgrading to the latest beta - Firefox 54.0b6 (32-bit) seems to resolve it.  I'm using the latest publicly available Flash Player (25.0.0.171) to test.  For completeness, I'm also unable to reproduce the problem on Chrome or IE on Win7 x64, or on Firefox with MacOS 10.12."

"Mozilla has been doing a lot of work on their rendering pipeline, and I suspect that the behavior you're seeing is fallout from that.  Since it's already fixed, it's just a matter of waiting for the changes to propagate to the release builds.  They're on a 6-week cycle, so assuming those fixes get promoted in the next release, you should see them land relatively soon."